# FedCM get() rejects with AbortError: The request has been aborted

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, google-signin, fedcm

I'm trying to implement the new FedCM api using Google sign-in. I'm currently developing my website locally and facing an issue: to improve UX, a cooldown is set in place to prevent the site from showing the "login with google" dialog too often.

I'm ok with that except that during development, I want to log in and log out a lot of times to test callbacks, features, etc.

I tried deleting the cookies, but after a short time, when calling `google.accounts.id.prompt()`, I'm hit with `FedCM get() rejects with AbortError: The request has been aborted.`

My init code is:

```
window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: 'myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        use_fedcm_for_prompt: true,
        callback: authenticationCallbackHandler
    });
    //google.accounts.id.prompt();
};
```

Writing `google.accounts.id.prompt();` directly in the browser console works.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are referring to the [cool-down period](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features#exponential_cooldown) when user clicks the Close X in the top-right corner of the prompt. For FedCM, different browser may have different settings on cool-down period or way to reset it. But for Chrome, you can reset the cooldown status by clocking the lock icon in the address bar and clicking *Reset Permission* button.

[image]