# prompt momentListener is not triggering when use_fedcm_for_prompt is true

Tags: javascript, google-signin, sign-in-with-google, fedcm

We are using Google One Tap prompt to signup/signin with Google account and initializing it as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.prompt). However, the momentListener is not triggering when `use_fedcm_for_prompt` is `true` but works fine if `use_fedcm_for_prompt` is `false`.

The GSI client library: `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`

We have below code:

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
    client_id: `<client_id>`,
    itp_support: true,
    use_fedcm_for_prompt: true,
});

google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    gsiButton.current as HTMLDivElement,
    renderGoogleButtonOptions
);

google.accounts.id.prompt((promptNotification) => {
    console.log('prompt callback', promptNotification);
});
```

In above code, the `google.accounts.id.prompt`'s `momentListener` is never triggered. **But disabling `use_fedcm_for_prompt` triggers the momentListener.**

I found below notes in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.prompt).

> Note: To improve user privacy, display moment notifications are intentionally delayed when FedCM is enabled. Notifications can be received up to 1 minute after the actual event took place.
>
> Note: For the native credential manager, there is no notification for display, skipped, or dismissed moments as these occur outside of the GIS library.

Not sure whether the takeaway is `momentListener` never gets triggered or triggered after a delay. I waited 10mins after the One Tap popup is shown and still the `momentListener` wasn't called.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it gives any hints, but look at [FedCM get() rejects with AbortError: The request has been aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76978782/fedcm-get-rejects-with-aborterror-the-request-has-been-aborted)

I am studying FedCM today and came upon your post here and also the above post.

Comment: It's a different issue. For me the One Tap works but the callback isn't called.